# Getting/looping a tree of variables from classes

Tags: python, python-2.x

How am I supposed to get a list of all variables from an object in python?

Example:
An Object is generated from a class, which can have (but not must, it various, the class is a black box, till now I can only detect the variables by tipping . and check the popup selection menu) variables in this form:

```
obj.Background.Picture.Embedded  
obj.Background.Picture.Path  
obj.Background.Picture.Style 
obj.Background.Picture.Visible
# ......
obj.DisplaySettings.DisplayFormat.Source.Dec.DisplaySign
obj.DisplaySettings.DisplayFormat.Source.Dec.Format
obj.DisplaySettings.DisplayFormat.Source.Dec.Precision
obj.DisplaySettings.DisplayFormat.Source.Dec.UsePrecision
# ......
obj.UniqueID
# .....
```

And the object may also have functions like:

```
Obj.MoveDown()
Obj.MoveUp()
# .....
Obj.Active()
Obj.Remove()
```

How am I supposed to get a list in string format like this?

```
VarList = ['obj.Background.Picture.Embedded', ... , 'Obj.DisplaySettings.DisplayFormat.Source.Dec.DisplaySign', ... , 'obj.UniqueID']
```

The purpose is to copy some of the variables from obj to obj. like:

```
Obj1.DisplaySettings.DisplayFormat.Source.Dec.DisplaySign = obj2.DisplaySettings.DisplayFormat.Source.Dec.DisplaySign
```

Because of some reason, variables like UniqueID should not be copied. Therefor using copy library is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`vars()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) to list all instance attributes directly on an object; it returns a dictionary:

```
 >>> vars(Obj)
 {'Background': <BackgroundType at 0x...>, 'DisplaySettings': <...>, ...}
```

or you can use [`dir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir), which returns a *list* of names on the instance and its parents (the class, baseclasses, their baseclasses, etc.):

```
>>> dir(Obj)
['__module__', '__name__', 'Active', 'Background', ...]
```

Many of the attributes on your object are more complex objects and have attributes of their own. You'd then inspect the `Background` object, for example:

```
>>> dir(Obj.Background)
[ ..., 'Picture', ...]
```

etc.

To copy across attributes, I'd stick with `vars()` and a loop to filter:

```
dec1 = Obj1.DisplaySettings.DisplayFormat.Source.Dec
dec2 = Obj2.DisplaySettings.DisplayFormat.Source.Dec
for name, value in vars(dec1).items():
    if name not in ('UniqueID', ...):
        setattr(dec2, name, value)
```

which would copy any names not listed in the tuple of names not to copy.

Comment: thank you! however using vars(obj) I get the result {'_oleobj_': <PyIDispatch at 0x2f31f44 with obj at 0x5ea46c>}. which has some functions like clear() copy() etc..

Comment: @user3327364: You need to consult the documentation of whatever OLE objects you are using (or the wrapper library) to see how to handle these. You have proxy objects for Windows objects here, not regular Python classes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
dir(obj)
```

gives you all member variables/functions of the object.